# Struts 2 Actions Redirect

Tags: java, redirect, struts2, actionresult

I am using Struts 2.

```
localhost:8084/Web/viewProductsAction?idProducts=1
```

After I see this product, I leave a comment.

And it successful but I got moved to

```
localhost:8084/Web/listProductsAction
```

Here is code in `struts.xml`:

```xml
<action name="listProductsAction" class="com.struts2.action.ProductsAction" method="viewProducts">
   <result name="success">/products.jsp</result>            
</action>
<action name="sendComments" class="com.struts2.action.CommentsAction" method="sendComments">
   <result name="success" type="redirect">listProductsAction</result>
</action>
```

But I want after leave a comment, it forward to

```
localhost:8084/Web/viewProductsAction?idProducts=1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the action config for the above url?

Comment: U mean web.xml file ?

Comment: You have posted only action configuration in xml for two actions `listProductsAction` and `sendComments`. What is the action configuration for `localhost:8084/Web/viewProductsAction?idProducts=1`?

Comment: <action name="viewProductsAction" class="com.struts2.action.ProductsAction" method="viewProducts">
       <result name="success">/products.jsp</result>            
    </action>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25685548/1654265

Answer (score 0):

Change the location of the `redirect` result to `redirectAction` result and location to `viewProductsAction`. After the post it will forward to the previous page.

```xml
<action name="sendComments" class="com.struts2.action.CommentsAction" method="sendComments">
   <result name="success" type="redirectAction">viewProductsAction?idProducts=1</result>
</action>
```

Comment: try that with parameter

Comment: I stuck in this point, how can i use parameter in struts.xml file

Comment: I try but it doesn't work. 

`<action name="sendComments" class="com.struts2.action.CommentsAction" method="sendComments">
   <param name="idProducts">${idProducts}</param>
   <result name="success" type="redirectAction">viewProductsAction?</result>
</action> `

Comment: Ok, i will try it tomorrow