# Passing javabean as parameter in struts.xml

Tags: struts2

```xml
<action name="someAction" class="">
    <result name="showDetails" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">someAction</param>
        <param name="method">someMethod</param>
        <param name="javabean.fieldOne">${javabean.fieldOne}</param>
        <param name="javabean.fieldTwo">${javabean.fieldTwo}</param>
        ...
        ...
    </result>
</action>
```

So instead of explicitly listing all the fields that I want to pass to the method, is it possible to pass the whole bean as parameter to the next action?

Note: I've tried `${javabean}`, but it gave me some class reference number as a string literal in an object. AFAIK, there's no way to recreate the object with this reference id.

Comment: Store it somewhere (e.g. session) and fetch in other action.

Comment: Your best solution is definitely to use the session; a workaround (more as an exercise of style than something that should be used in a real world application), however, is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25685548/1654265

Comment: You can use one parameter that will keep the whole bean serialized to string.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've solved the problem by storing the javabean in session. Thanks again.