# struts2 action redirect to servlet with parameters

Tags: redirect, servlets, struts2, http-request-parameters, servlet-dispatching

I would like to find out if there is a way to redirect struts 2 action result to a servlet with the request parameters intact?

I am wondering if I can something similar like https://struts.apache.org/docs/dispatcher-result.html:

```
<result name="success" type="dispatcher">
  <param name="location">/MyServlet</param>
</result>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts2 is meant to be used with Actions.

When redirecting across actions with the `redirectAction` result, you can pass a fixed number of known parameters, assigning them both name and the value dynamically.

When redirecting to a Servlet with the `redirect` result, you can pass the parameters in the QueryString.

If you want to automatically grab an unknown number of parameters in the request and pass it to a Servlet, you should code it yourself. 
You're lucky though, [I've already did it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25685548/1654265).

Comment: Can it be done using https://struts.apache.org/docs/dispatcher-result.html?

Comment: Dispatcher result, that is the default result, does dispatch a JSP; it does not redirect to anywhere

Comment: I wanted to pass some parameters to my servlet via query string. How can I do so via the struts action result?

Comment: With the redirect result, or like RomanC suggested, by excluding a particular pattern from Struts2 filter and forwarding there with the dispatcher result. Both ways work